# Branch for log(f(z))

Tags: complex-analysis

If I'm given the function $\log(z-z^2)$ how to prove that it's holomorphic on it's domain?

**Attempt:** Since $\log z$ is multivariated we need to cut the branch $(-\infty,1]$, but since $z-z^2<1$ is always true in the whole real axis, the domain I think should be $\mathbb{C}\backslash\ (-\infty,\infty)$, is it fine?

Comment: Please do not change the question after receiving answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $D \subset \Bbb C$ is any simply connected domain not containing the points $0$ and $1$ then $f(z) = z-z^2$ is holomorphic and non-zero in $D$, so that a holomorphic branch of $\log(f(z))$ exists.

A simple choice would be $D = \Bbb C \setminus \left( (-\infty, 0] \cup [1, \infty) \right)$. $f(z) = z-z^2 = 1/4-(z-1/2)^2$ maps $D$ onto $\Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$, on which the principal branch of the logarithm is defined.

Comment: Can I say that since $z-z^2$ is holomorphic, and since $log$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\backslash (-\infty,0]$ then $log f$ is holomorphic right?

Comment: $z-z^2$ is holomorphic from $D$ into $G = \Bbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$, and the principal branch of the logarithm is holomorphic in $G$. The composition of holomorphic functions is holomorphic.